# System constant for the number of days in a week (7)

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, date

Can anyone find a constant in the .NET framework that defines the number of days in a week (7)?

```
DateTime.DaysInAWeek // Something like this???
```

Of course I can define my own, but I'd rather not if it's somewhere in there already.

### Update:

I am looking for this because I need to allow the user to select a week (by date, rather than week number) from a list in a DropDownList.

Comment: That reminds me of a comment that said you shouldn't use hardcoded 3.14159... but do a "#define PI 3.14159...", should the value of PI ever change in the future.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could probably use [System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.DayNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.daynames.aspx).Length.

Answer (score 9):

I think it's ok to harcode this one. I don't think it will change any soon.

*Edit: I depends where you want to use this constant. Inside the some calendar related algorithm it is obvious what 7 means. On the other hand sometimes named constant make code much more readable.*

Comment: Still better to use a named constant so that anyone reading the code knows what it is and doesn't have to wonder whether it's just the developer's lucky number.

Comment: Also, it could change if you want to calculate something based on a 5 day working week instead of all 7 days?

Comment: I've got 25 years experience in every language from Ada to C to Ruby, and I'm not sure about whether to use a named constant for this. My current large app is a calendaring system and I'm using "7"'s in many places and find it very readable. eg `weekCount*7`. My gut is to stay with the "7".

Comment: After reading the comments I still think that using a named constant is always better. It doesn't have any downside and it's increasing readability, and the fact that something won't change doesn't really matter IMO. Besides, what if the logic would change from days in a week to works days and stuff like that? that **can** and even a bit likely to happen. Also the fact that different cultures have different length of weeks also adds some concerns about hard-coding `7`.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
Enum.GetNames(System.DayOfWeek).Length
```

Comment: That'll work, but keep in mind that the MSDN documentation for the DayOfWeek enum says that it's only valid in cultures who have a seven-day week.

Comment: Having said that, I'm not sure that there are any cultures that don't have a seven day week! :)

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the IL code for Calendar.AddWeeks you will see that Microsoft itself uses a hardcoded 7 in the code.

Also the [rotor source](http://www.123aspx.com/Rotor/RotorSrc.aspx?rot=40097) uses a hardcoded 7.

Still, I would suggest to use a const.

Comment: You can't tell from the IL whether it is a literal 7 or a constant defined elsewhere, as constants are resolved at compile time.

Comment: OK, but there is also no constant definition. Looked it up in rotor.

Comment: I think what Greg meant is that you wouldn't see one either way, because after compilation there's no sign for constant definitions (in contrast for readonly fields for example, in order to improve performances).

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is one.  TimeSpan defines constants for the number of ticks per milli/second/minute/hour/day, but nothing at the level of a week.

I ran a query across the standard libraries for symbols (methods/constants/fields/etc) containing the word 'Week'.  Nothing came back.  FYI, I ran this query using ReSharper.

Answer (score 2):

I used this:

```
public static readonly int WeekNumberOfDays = Enum.GetNames(typeof(DayOfWeek)).Length;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you're looking for, but you can try [DateHelper (CODE.MSDN)](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/datehelper/). It's a library I put together for typical date needs. You might be able to use the week methods or the List methods. [method list](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/datehelper/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Method%20List&referringTitle=Home)

Edit - no more MSDN code, not on GitHub as part of lib: https://github.com/tbasallo/toolshed

Comment: Your links don't return anything with the DateHelper name. Just main page for MSDN samples.

Comment: ooof. It's been a while since Code MSDN was even a thing. Here: It' spart of tis lib now: https://github.com/tbasallo/toolshed

Answer (score 0):

[`GregorianCalendar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.gregoriancalendar(v=vs.110).aspx) has [`AddWeeks(1)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.addweeks(v=vs.110).aspx) which will add 7 days to a date.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean calendar weeks or just common weeks?

Obviously, there are calendar weeks that might be shortrer than seven days. The last calendar week of the year is usually shorter, and depending on your definition of calendar week, the first week might be shorter as well.

In that case, I'm afraid you will have to roll out your own week length function. It's not really hard to do with the `DateTime` class, I did it before, if you need more help let me know.

Comment: Just create a constant in your class then if you really want to avoid hardcoding numbers, even well-known ones.