# Get 7 day names and numbers in a week and insert into dictionary using C#

Tags: c#

Hi I am trying to populate a dictionary with all the day names and numbers in a week, I have written a following method to achieve that;

```
public static Dictionary<int, string> GetDaysOfWeek()
{
    Dictionary<int, string> daysOfWeek = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
    {
        daysOfWeek.Add(i, Enum.GetName(typeof(DayOfWeek), i));
    }
    return daysOfWeek;
}
```

I am getting first 6 values up to Saturday fine, but somehow the day name property is null for Sunday, I don't know if I am missing something here.

Also, I was looking for some existing method that can give me all the days and their numbers, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419707/system-constant-for-the-number-of-days-in-a-week-7) which is near, but it only gives day name. Is there any existing function or property in c# that can give me desired output?

Comment: Isn't Sunday enum 0? So, int i = 0 to i < 7?

Comment: Try daysOfWeek.Add(i, Enum.GetName(typeof(DayOfWeek), I % 7));

Comment: You can post the code of your enum?

Comment: By the way. This is incredibly bad form as it does not deal with Cultures properly. You should look at `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing to this

```
public static Dictionary<int, string> GetDaysOfWeek()
{
    Dictionary<int, string> daysOfWeek = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        daysOfWeek.Add(i, Enum.GetName(typeof(DayOfWeek), i));
    }

    return daysOfWeek;
}
```

or if you want to keep the day order you can do this

```
public static Dictionary<int, string> GetDaysOfWeek()
{
    Dictionary<int, string> daysOfWeek = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
    {
        daysOfWeek.Add(i, Enum.GetName(typeof(DayOfWeek), i % 7));
    }

    return daysOfWeek;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Or another way: `foreach (var day in new [] { DayOfWeek.Sunday, DayOfWeek.Monday, .. })`. (But then arguably, why not have the names themselves as strings?)

Comment: Erm its a bit overkill isn't it? There is a framework method for this.

Answer (score 3):

Actually there is no need to do any coding at all.

```
public static string[] GetDaysOfWeek()
{
    return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames;
}
```

Notice that you can index an array in the same way as you can index a Dictionary.