# How to get the amount of days in a certain month using a weeknumber and yearnumber C#

Tags: c#, .net

i have a object that has a weeknumber and a yearnumber.

what i want to know is how many days of a week are in a certain month.

For example:

week 52 from 2022 has 6 days in december 2022 and 1 day in january of 2023.

```
findAmountOfDaysInMont(52, 2022, 12) // this shoud return 6

// weeknumber is the weeknumber of the object
// year is the yearnumber of the object
// searchMonth is the month that i want to check
void findAmountOfDaysInMont(int weeknumber, int year, int searchMonth)
{
...
}
```

Comment: [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31716937/get-number-of-days-in-a-week) could be a viable duplicate. But why do you need the month if you now the absolute week? Week 52 will never be in march... and please don't ask us to write the entire code for you....

Comment: @MongZhu: If a week spans 2 months, the month to query does make sense.